# Is a lagrangian with a background field interaction renormalizable ? If yes, when?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, renormalization

Consider the Lagrangian,

$$ L = -\partial_{\mu} \chi \partial_{\nu} \chi^{\dagger} - m^2 \chi \chi^{\dagger} + g\chi \chi^{\dagger}\phi,$$

where $\phi$ is a background field and $\chi$ is a complex scalar field. Is this theory renormalizable? If yes, for what values of $\phi$ is it renormalizable?

Comment: Isn't that just a free theory?  (Possibly Lorentz-violating depending on the background but that's ok)

Comment: @Andrew How is it free if it interacts with a static background field ?

Comment: Free in the sense of, quadratic in $\chi$. So, all the connected $n$ point functions for $\chi$ should be zero.  For example if \phi$ is constant the net result as far as $\chi$ is concerned is to redress the mass of $\chi$--no loops or divergences. Now sometimes the background field method is used to compute corrections for the action of the background field, so for example you can compute the quantum corrections to the potential for $\phi$. That could be interesting here, especially if you allowed for higher powers of $\phi$, but I'm not sure if that's what you're asking or not.